# Show AdWords for some users

Tags: google-adsense

I'm thinking of placing AdSense on my site, but I'd hate to show AdSense to my paying customers.

Does AdSense policy allow this - showing AdSense only for some users - or do they require that they are shown to all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes can do that. Just like you do not have to show ads on every page.

Depending on how your site is implemented, the paying pages may have a different URL and therefore would be considered different pages.

Since I assume, the Googlebot is not a paying customer, they shouldn't even be able to see that!

Answer (score 1):

Since you wish to put ads on *your* site, I hope you're talking about Adsense. (Adwords are ads that are put by advertisers alongside Google search results and on *others* website.)

I don't think Google will have any problem with Adsense showing up only for non-paying members. Just make sure you comply with their regular TOS and you should be ok.

Comment: Yes, I meant AdSense, I'll clarify